# How can i recreate this lighting that an AI made

Tags: lighting

Basically i wanted to practice lighting a scene so i used an AI image generator (DALL-E 2) to create this first image and have set it as a target, the second is my own attempt and I’m looking so get some proper directions as to what to do.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Use photographs for reference for lighting. It's not realistic, what AI generates. And your work doesn't have to be realistic, but reality is a very good starting point to keep it believable.

Comment: Use textures. You need some scratches and smudges for your metal surface as well as a texture for your floor. Then, a strong enough light will highlight differences in the textures and bring life to the render.

Comment: I’m more thinking of the lighting right now rather than the texturing.
The references lighting is more spread out whilst still keeping focus on the object whereas mine is not doing either well.

Comment: Start with a point light, and keep moving it away and increasing its strength until you get the needed coverage.